# efficient way to clip video + audio with out exporting on veed

Tags: video-editor, editing

I am using veed.io to edit some videos, I am syncing video + audio, as the first step, then I have to clip mistake parts and delete them...

I have discovered that is faster to sync them, export that as a new video, then clip the new video, because if I clip the video and sound tracks some times they move and loose the sync, or other errors happen, so is there a way to join the video and audio in veed with out exporting?